# Getting the distance in a straight line (radius) between two points using the HERE api

Tags: php, api, curl, maps

I am using the HERE api to calculate a distance between two points following a route with a car. I check in my code if a distance is longer than 25km an error message pops up. Now I need to alter my code to not check for 25km distance in a car route, but a straight line, so a 25km radius from point A to point B.

Is this possible with the HERE api? I cannot find any documentation on it. Google maps is not an option unfortunately since they are now a subscription based model.

Currently I get my distance between a route with the following code:

```
$coordinatecustomerencoded = urlencode('geo!'.$latitudecustomer.','.$longitudecustomer);
$conditionsencoded = urlencode('fastest;car;traffic:disabled');

// Put headers inside array
$distanceheaders = array();
// The URL where a curl request is made to
$distanceurl = 'https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!51.8284405,4.2560131&waypoint1='.$coordinatecustomerencoded.'&mode='.$conditionsencoded.'&app_id=myappid&app_code=myapicode';
$distancecurl = curl_init($distanceurl);
curl_setopt($distancecurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($distancecurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $distanceheaders);

// The JSON response
$distanceresponse = curl_exec($distancecurl);
```